# how to add set of code blocks in center of two column page

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, minipage

I hope you are doing very well. I am trying to add code the two the two column pages. I am using verbatim to add code to my papers.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,sigconf,natbib=false]{acmart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\fvset{
  frame=topline,
  numbers=left,
  framesep=3mm,
  xleftmargin=16pt,
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Verbatim}[label=Original Code]
class C {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f() {
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[label=duplication code]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[label=Programming]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}[label=C Code]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}
\begin{Verbatim}[label= Extract Local]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

It has some issues, Firstly I want to move code of block from vertical to horizental. Like this
[image]

I have tried, But I can not bold some words in code using Verbatim. I want to bold somewords and also change the backgroud "grey" color of that specific bold color, such as words "class, public, new (bold + background grey color)" and these code of blocks should be at the start of the page with caption. I think, Verbatim does not support bold and colors, What other methods can be used to perform these actions ?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a page-wide block in a two-column document, you can use

```
\begin{figure*} ... \end{figure*}
```

but then the thing will be put on the top of a page. There are packages that allow these to be put mid-page (e.g. midfloat), but I would suggest to use the package `multicol` instead of the `twocolumn` option to better mix double and single columns.

For making pieses of text bold and/or colored in `Verbatim` use the `commandchars=` option. The characters that you specify there should not occur in your text, or if you need them you have to replace them by commands that generate these characters.

For example, if you specify `commandchars={@[]}` but you want to use `[` and `]` in the text you can define `\[` to generate `[`, and `\]` to generate `]` (as you don't use math mode in verbatim this is safe if you do it locally) and then use `@[` and `@]` in your code.

```
\documentclass[sigconf,natbib=false]{acmart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\fvset{
  frame=topline,
  numbers=left,
  framesep=3mm,
  xleftmargin=16pt,
}
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\parskip=\baselineskip
\def\[{[}\def\]{]}

  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[label=Original Code,commandchars={@[]}]
@red[class] C {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f() {
  @[...@]
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}
  \end{minipage}
\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[label=duplication code]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[label=Programming]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}
  \end{minipage}
\hfill
  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[label=C Code]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}
  \end{minipage}

  \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{Verbatim}[label= Extract Local]
class c {
  public X x = new X();

  public void f(){
  ...
  }
}
\end{Verbatim}
  \end{minipage}
  
  \caption{Abstraction method}
\end{figure}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \lipsum
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Bless you